# Time Function not correctly calculating

Tags: php, mysql

My time calculations are not correct I have a time.php that is called in my profile.php to calculate the last time a message was sent etc

I have the following line that calls the function time_passed for the row time

```
echo "time_passed"($row['time']);
```

Here is the CODE for calculating time

```
   <?php

  // DISPLAYS COMMENT POST TIME AS "1 year, 1 week ago" or "5 minutes, 7    seconds ago", etc...
 function time_passed($timestamp){
//type cast, current time, difference in timestamps
$timestamp      = (int) $timestamp;
$current_time   = time();
$diff           = $current_time - $timestamp;

//intervals in seconds
$intervals      = array (
    'year' => 31556926, 'month' => 2629744, 'week' => 604800, 'day' => 86400, 'hour' => 3600, 'minute'=> 60
);

//now we just find the difference
if ($diff == 0)
{
    return 'just now';
}    

if ($diff < 60)
{
    return $diff == 1 ? $diff . ' second ago' : $diff . ' seconds ago';
}        

if ($diff >= 60 && $diff < $intervals['hour'])
{
    $diff = floor($diff/$intervals['minute']);
    return $diff == 1 ? $diff . ' minute ago' : $diff . ' minutes ago';
}        

if ($diff >= $intervals['hour'] && $diff < $intervals['day'])
{
    $diff = floor($diff/$intervals['hour']);
    return $diff == 1 ? $diff . ' hour ago' : $diff . ' hours ago';
}    

if ($diff >= $intervals['day'] && $diff < $intervals['week'])
{
    $diff = floor($diff/$intervals['day']);
    return $diff == 1 ? $diff . ' day ago' : $diff . ' days ago';
}    

if ($diff >= $intervals['week'] && $diff < $intervals['month'])
{
    $diff = floor($diff/$intervals['week']);
    return $diff == 1 ? $diff . ' week ago' : $diff . ' weeks ago';
}    

if ($diff >= $intervals['month'] && $diff < $intervals['year'])
{
    $diff = floor($diff/$intervals['month']);
    return $diff == 1 ? $diff . ' month ago' : $diff . ' months ago';
}    

if ($diff >= $intervals['year'])
{
    $diff = floor($diff/$intervals['year']);
    return $diff == 1 ? $diff . ' year ago' : $diff . ' years ago';
}
}

?>
```

The result is as follows

[image]

My table is

[image]

The time is inserted in the following format

[image]

The time gets inserted automatically when a query is ran,   then I show back the results in a table above but its says 46 years ago , What is possible causing this ? Thanks

Comment: Somewhere along the line your date/time format is invalid for PHP to work with

Comment: I don't understand the end of your post where you show how the time is inserted. Your script takes a `timestamp` as its parameter. Could you give us a timestamp you tried, what you expected and what outputted instead?

Comment: you're inputting the time in hh:mm:ss as stated, but your function expects a timestamp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just you need to do the following

change this line  `$timestamp  = (int) $timestamp;` to

```
$timestamp  = strtotime($timestamp);
```

and add the default time for your country. For example as I am from India I used to set `date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');` at the starting of function

Comment: Thanks for that help

Comment: No problem .Happy to help :)

Comment: Do you possible know why the time goes to -28025 seconds ago after 5 + hrs of no activity . I have added the above answer which works however after some time passes the time displays as -numbers , It updates again though as soon as I place a new posts to normal time .

Comment: Yes . because you are checking only with the time not with date and time. If the current time is 08:00:00 and posted time is 10:00:00 yesterday .It is doing like 8 -10 like calculation

Comment: Thanks again , It works now I updated to DATETIME in my table . All other older times are displaying as normal . Brilliant !